# What is the name for a 3 pointed figure with two straight sides and an arc?

Tags: geometry, terminology

For example, if one draws a circle inside of a star so that the circumference touches all of the inner points --- it would be the opposite of a sector --- the red part in the image below:

[image]

I would like to use the correct term for a series of macros/module names --- would "cove" be acceptable?

Comment: No special name.  If we had to name this, though, there would be innumerable other figures to name (two curved plus one straight, three curved, ...)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the only shape which I need which doesn't have a name (you can see the list at: https://wiki.shapeoko.com/index.php/Design_into_3D#Toolpaths --- FWIW, 3 curves would be Deltoid curve (three concave arcs)
Reuleaux triangle (three convex arcs)
Arbelos (one convex, two concave arcs), two curves with a straight line would be some portion of a lens or lune... corrections/additions would be welcome) so unless there's some better suggestion, I guess I'll just use "cove".

Comment: You're looking for a *general* term, but the Reuleaux triangle has *very* specific properties (cannot fit through a certain hole...).

Comment: I'm willing to abuse a specific term for more general --- I'll just note that in the comments for the software package.

Comment: My choice would be to pick an outrageous name, such as "cosector", that I have to define, and that the reader will obviously understand as a nonce technical term, and so pay attention to my definition.

Comment: Making a "non-sense" name is an absolutely atrocious and demonic approach... clouding understanding of those who take the time to study a topic.  Imagine all the intuitive terms you know were instead some "non-sense" term!  Suppose terms like "group" and "dimension" were replaced by "non-sense" terms that rejected the connections to intuitive terms... so we used "flap-doodle" and "gorgonzola" for these!!  "Non-sense" terms like "Reuleaux" are chosen to honor the mathematician who devised the concept and term.  (Even your incorrect "nonce" confuses readers... e.g., non-native English speakers.)

Comment: An appropriate name would be [*dunce cap*](https://myheadcoverings.wordpress.com/tag/history-of-the-dunce-cap/).